# Ionic View build app with unsupported plugin

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-view

I'm trying to use `cordova-plugin-file` inside a APP in Ionic View, but, according to this [list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/view.html#plugin-support), it isn't supported in Ionic View.

I've 2 questions about it:

1. There's a way to build it before sending it to Ionic View?
2. When I put my APP in production via Ionic Pro, will I still have this problem?

Thanks in advance!